# How to turn off Thunderbolt charging on Mac Book Pro so that only the main MagSafe charger is used?

Tags: battery, thunderbolt, charging, power, magsafe

I use a Mac Book Pro (MBP18,2) in a primarily office setting and have it plugged in essentially all of the time. This is, of course, detrimental to the battery. I'd like to allow it to drain and use the battery in order to prolong its life, but I also simultaneously require two Thunderbolt hubs to be attached for external monitors that I require for work.

Having the Thunderbolt hubs/"docks" plugged in charges the system even when the MagSafe power cord is detached.

Is there a way to disable Thunderbolt charging so that only the MagSafe power adapter will work and thus allow proper battery "exercising" in this scenario?

Comment: I understand your motivation, and I would likely share them - however if it's truly going to be plugged in all the time, the system optimization will kick in and while it won't be as ambitious as, say, 50% or 80% - it will reduce it notably.

Comment: However, you won't see this effect if it's plugged in all the time because unlike the charging optimization that pins it to lower percentages until it thinks your about to start using it, the always-plugged-in optimization actually rewrites "100%" to a different amount.

Comment: Apps like coconut battery will reveal this - you'll see that it doesn't reach 100% with those apps. Anyways, if you can't find a different solution I recommend leaving it like this for a week or two and using coconut Battery to see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is not precisely what you are asking for, but have you considered using the [AlDente](https://apphousekitchen.com) app? With it, you can set a maximum battery percentage threshold and it will prevent charging regardless of USB-C or MagSafe connections.

Comment: Indeed not exactly what I'm wanting, but this could perhaps be workable. My intention was to try an app called FruitJuice to see how that might do which seems to be interesting, but maybe these two can work together, etc. At the least this aldente seems to perhaps help... Thanks and I'll give it a spin for a bit to see where we go.

Comment: After some testing AlDente seems to kinda do the job. I'm somewhat pleased, but the instructions are a bit lacking or not as clear as they could be in some areas. Appreciate the suggestion and I've been using it now in hopes that it will stop the downward trend of my poor laptop battery.